# Aligning minipages inside list environment

Tags: spacing, lists, minipage

I use an own environment to typeset exercises with exercise-numbering at the left and exercise-body at the right.

When I want to put two minipages in the exercise-body, they aren't aligned anymore with the exercise-number. `\noindent`before the minipage dosen't work.

See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\exlmargin}
\setlength{\exlmargin}{0.1\textwidth}

\newcounter{exnum}
\setcounter{exnum}{1}
\newcommand*{\points}{}

\newenvironment{exc}[1]{%
    \renewcommand*{\points}{#1}%
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\exlmargin}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}%
    }%
    \item[]%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%  % Put a null-wide box for exercise number.
        \hspace{-\parindent}%
        \hspace{-\exlmargin}%
        \makebox[\exlmargin][l]{\arabic{exnum}\refstepcounter{exnum}}%
        \hss%   % Put a infinite shrink (and stretch) to avoid overfull of th null-wide box.
    }%
    \ignorespaces}{%    % Let (La)TeX ignore the spaces following
    \ifnum \points>0 \hspace*{0pt} \hfill \mbox{(\points\ PTS)} \fi%
    \end{list}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{exc}{4}
    \lipsum*[2]
\end{exc}

\begin{exc}{2}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}\vspace{0pt}
        \lipsum*[2]
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}\vspace{0pt}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
\end{exc}

\end{document}
```

[image: No alignment between the 2 and the body while using minipages.]

What to do to align the number and the body while using minipages?

BTW: Any clue how to get the *(2 PTS)* aligned with the last line of the left minipage?

### Edit

I realized that the spacing has also an issue when using a tabular in the exercise-body:

```
\begin{exc}{2}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        text&text\\
        text&text\\
        text&text\\
    \end{tabular}\par
\end{exc}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove those `\vspace{0pt}` inside the `minipage`s. Adjust the base line of tikz picture using `baseline` option to `tikzpicture`.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-10.343pt]current bounding box.north)}]`

Comment: Nice, thanks. Is the -10.343pt found by bruteforce or is there a direct way to know this?

Comment: Maybe there is... But I just zoomed in very much and compared to an f-box around the left minipage.

Comment: I realized there are also spacing problems when using a tabu (or a tabular) instead of two minipages. Also any special option here to use?